# 初心者の質問タイトルや内容を編集してしまうのとコメントで促すのはどちらがbe-niceか？

Tags: 討議, サポート, 編集

はじめまして。タイトルの通りなのですが、質問の一覧を定期的に眺めていると
記憶にあった質問が突然見当たらなくなり、よくよく見てみると質問タイトルが
編集によって書き替えられているという例をみかけます。

これは、複数回の質問をして、スタックオーバーフローでの質問は権限を持った
人が書き替え、より統一されれ見やすい形に常にメンテしてくれる人がいるもの
であることを理解した人にはありがたいことだと思うのですが、
初めてやそれに近い質問回数の人には何かいけないことをしてしまったのでは無いかという
戸惑いと敷居の高さを感じさせる原因になってしまうのではないか？と思いました。

そこで、メタをご覧の皆様にお伺いしたいのですが、特に初心者に限って
質問の内容やタイトルをいきなり書き替えるよりは、まずコメント等で
自主的な改題や内容の修正を促すのと、そのプロセスを省いていきなり改題や
内容の修正を行ってしまうことはどちらが初心者にとってbe-niceなのか
ご意見を伺いたいと思い、投稿させて頂きました。

Comment: 皆様。いろいろなご意見ありがとうございます。心情的には@greenteaさんのお考えが自分に一番近く感じたのですが。どの回答にも納得できるところが充分にあり、悩みましたが、@nekketsuuuさんのスタンスを、小規模な編集に留めることで最大限の効果を得る適切な落としどころと感じたため、回答を承認させて頂きました。これに懲りず疑問に感じることがあった際は、また質問させて頂くかも知れませんが、その際もよろしくお付き合い下さいますようお願いします。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ご質問の中で最も重要なのは質問したい内容であり装飾ではないと考えているため、投稿を改善し質問内容が変わらないだろう範囲の小さな編集は、特に通知せずにしてしまっています。特にスタック・オーバーフローに初めていらっしゃった方には、コミュニティが決めた細かいルールよりかは、質問と回答に集中して頂きたいからです。

より具体的には、だいたい以下のことはそのまま編集しています。編集後にコメントで残すこともあります。また、2回目以降はコメントでお願いすることが多いです。

- タグを整理すること
- 小さな誤字を修正すること
- コード部分などで Markdown の装飾を整えること
- タグ的な文字列をタイトルから削除すること
- 質問内容を具体的にするために、コメントの内容を本文へ追記すること
- スクリーンショットから文字起こしをすること
- タイトルが質問内容をより具体的に表すよう、文字を追加すること（エラーメッセージなど）

これ以外のことは、一度コメントで確認を取ったり、そもそも編集しないようにすることが多いです。

ただ今回のご投稿を見て、タイトルが質問内容を具体的に表すよう編集するのは、コメントで確認してからの方が良いな、と考えを改めました。エラー内容を追加する程度なら良いと思いますが、全体的に手直しするのは一度確認を通すようにしたいと思います。

やや関連?: ["What is the etiquette for modifying posts?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474/341401) -- Stack Exchange Meta

Comment: ありがとうございます。あくまでも「そういう人もいるのではないか？」という心配だけで、タイトルなどを変更されて戸惑っている方を具体的に見かけたわけではないことをご了承ください

Answer (score 5):

質問に対しては基本的にコメントで指摘し、暫くした後に改善が見られない場合に修正を行っております。
ただコードをハイライトする程度などの簡単な修正で、質問文が読み取れなくなっているような場合であれば
即時で修正を行っております。

SOにあまりなれていない方、Markdownと言われて分からない方にとって
まず必要なのは慣れていただくことだと考えております。
なれるためには"コミュニティに修正を行ってもらう"ことよりも、"指摘され質問者が修正する"方が良いと思います。

操作方法が分からないから触っていただくのもありますが、
修正コメントなどの存在を慣れていない方は知らないと思いますので、
"どうして修正されたか？"が分からないまま次も同じような書き方をしてしまうものと考えております。
また、どうしても修正しないといけない場合であってもコメントは残すようにしております。

以上のことから、個人的な考えではありますが、基本的にはコメントで指摘して修正してもらう方針で考えております。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。概ね同じ意見なのですが、一つ確認させてください。「"修正を行ってもらう"ことよりも、"指摘され修正する"方が良い」は「"（第三者に）修正を行ってもらう"ことよりも、"指摘され（質問者が）修正する"方が良い」という解釈でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @Чайка そういう意図で書きましたので、そうです。

Comment: 間違った解釈をしていなくて安心しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4):

自分の感覚ですが、、、
質問内容を編集されて、分かり易く直してもらって助かったという人と、自分の意図とは違うと思う人がいると思います。
また、見ている方としては、履歴を全て見ている人は少ないと思うので、どの時点で見るかで印象は変わりますが、、、
自分としては、気になる質問があった、とその後、見た時に、消えていたと感じる事が時々あります。きちんと把握している訳ではないので、見逃しかも知れませんが、最近は、編集の結果と思う事があります。(特にタイトル)  また、編集が、質問者の意図に沿ったものか、分からないと感じる事もあり、本当に必要かと感じています。
自分の感覚としては、編集結果が本来の質問の意図に一致しているかどうか判断できませんが、編集している人はその心配はしないのでしょうか?　質問者もすぐに確認できると思えないし、勝手に書き換えられたと思う人がいても不思議は無いとおもうのですが、どうでょうか? 
個人的には、不用意な個人情報とか、誹謗中傷以外は、他人が編集すべきでは無いと思っています。 また、質問者の立場で考えると、質問文を添削されるより、回答なり、ヒントを提示してくれた方が、嬉しいと思います。 (特になかなか回答が付かないもの)

Comment: 僕もそう思って質問しました。が、僕がこの質問を投稿した後でも、初質問でもタイトルや内容が編集された方がいいという意見がないにもかかわらず、タイトルや内容が編集されていることに疑問を感じています

Comment: @Чайка さん、私の投稿は部分的に編集を許していて、特にタイトルへ文字を追加して内容を限定することについて許していることにご注意ください。また、この質問投稿以降、数人の方がコメントで編集を示唆してくださるようになっていると感じることも付記いたします。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん。仰るとおりですね。失念していました。すみませんでした。

Comment: 回答済みとなっているを書き換えられると、何が正しいのか分からなくなりますね。 質問も書き換えられて、ミスマッチかも知れませんが、そこまで確認する気になれないので、未確認。 書式見直しっぽいですが、ブロックで書き換えられると分からない。

Comment: 改めて、自分の更新分と差分を見るとそんなに違ってなかったが、この程度の編集は余計なお世話。

Comment: [こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/44495/%e6%a7%8b%e9%80%a0%e4%bd%93%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%ad%e3%81%ae%e3%83%9d%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e5%a4%89%e6%95%b0%e3%82%92%e3%82%82%e3%81%a4%e6%a7%8b%e9%80%a0%e4%bd%93%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e5%90%84%e3%80%85%e3%81%ae%e3%83%a1%e3%83%b3%e3%83%90%e3%81%ab%e5%80%a4%e3%82%92%e4%bb%a3%e5%85%a5%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84/44496#44496)でしょうか？気に障ったようで失礼しました。

Comment: 最新に「編集」を見て、"あっ、コードが書き換えられている"、次に、"自分でミスったと思った箇所がそのまま"　でした。 「動いているコードは変えるな」と言う職場で働いていたので、ちょっと過剰反応だったでしょうか。 ただ、整形したと言われて、バグを埋め込まれた

Comment: (続き。うっかり、Enterすると、、) ただ、整形したと言われて、バグを埋め込まれた事が多々、あります。コメントでさえ、修正ついでに、改行コードまで消すという素晴らしい(?) 修正される方が居るので、要注意という習慣が身についています。 (原因を探すのが大変だった)　また、回答が確定したら、やはり触らない方が、安全では無いかと改めて思います。

Answer (score 1):

正に表題の通り、先日質問タイトルを "内容に対して適切ではないか" と思う内容に編集したことがあります。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/44276/revisions

私個人としても、コメントで指摘し、本人に修正していただいたほうが良い経験になるのでは？と思っています。しかし、スタック・オーバフローの仕様上、信用度が50を超えないと質問にコメントする権限が付与されません。質問の件名・内容の編集(のリクエスト)は可能です。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

そのため、私のように信用度の低いユーザでは "件名・内容の編集(のリクエスト)" のみが選択肢となってしまいます。このあたり、仕様がうまく調整可能であれば良いなと思います。

Comment: スタックオーバーフローにアカウントを作って結構な時間が経ってしまったので、コメント権限より先に編集権限が付くことをすっかり忘れていました。確かにコメントする権限が内容を編集する権限より後というのは不思議な気がしますね

Comment: 「編集する権限」ではなく「編集リクエストを送る権限」なので、より高い信用度を持つユーザーに承認されないと実際には編集されません。スタック・オーバーフローは質問フォーラムというよりかは wiki のような存在なので、編集のための機能が先に開放されるのが自然かなあと私は感じました。（ちょっと個人の感性って感じもしますね、、、汗）

Comment: このような議題で結論を出す、というのは難しそうですね。モデレータの方々がユーザ体験の向上を考え、公開の場で意見を交わしているのが拝見できるのは良いですね。

Comment: 結論が出ずとも考える種になれば良いかなぁと思います。

Comment: 承認やモデレートについては別になりそうですが、編集承認時にコメントついていなければ付けてあげてもいいんじゃないかと思いました。

Comment: 編集とコメントがミスマッチになっている事がありますね。ただ、先にも書きましたが、質問に対する回答が欲しいですね。質問者が欲しいのはそちらでしょうから。