# 質問には自分の考えた手法による解決方法の手段が知りたいとあるが、本当にやりたいことをするにはその解決方法は関係なかった場合の質問タイトルを変更したほうがよいか

Tags: 討議, 編集

[javascript - getselection contenteditable buttonを押す前の状態を取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69756/getselection-contenteditable-button%e3%82%92%e6%8a%bc%e3%81%99%e5%89%8d%e3%81%ae%e7%8a%b6%e6%85%8b%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

上記の質問について、質問者さんは、熱心に色々試した結果だと思うのですが、自分がやりたいこと（`ユーザーが選択している文字列を取得したい、ただし特定のdivタグ内のものに限る`）をするためには、`buttonを押す前の状態を取得する` ものだと考え、質問のタイトルもそのようになっています。

しかしコメントや実際に回答してみたところ、`buttonを押す前の状態を取得する`はまったく関係ないことがわかりました。この場合タイトルを、`ユーザーが選択している文字列を取得したい、ただし特定のdivタグ内のものに限る`といった内容に変更したほうがいいのでしょうか？　タイトルを変更するのは少しやりすぎな気もするのですが、あとから来た人がなにかもっとわかりやすくするための工夫はできないものでしょうか？

Comment: 関連しそうなメタ投稿: [初心者の質問タイトルや内容を編集してしまうのとコメントで促すのはどちらがbe-niceか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2697)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

変更が些細なもので、かつ自分が行おうとしている変更内容に自信があれば直接編集して構いませんが、
質問の内容や印象が変わってしまいそうであれば、まずは質問者に **コメントで確認** することをおすすめします。

[コメントに関するヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) にも、以下のような記載があります。

> - (投稿の) 作成者に明確化をリクエストする

特に、まだスタック・オーバーフローに不慣れなユーザーにとっては自分の投稿が編集されることに慣れておらず、「編集合戦」のようなことになってしまうのを避けるためにも、投稿者本人の意思を確認しながらの方が良いのかなと思います。